# Is it possible to use two toolboxes at once?

Tags: matlab, toolbox, lego-mindstorms

I need to write a code that allows a Lego Mindstorms Ev3 robot to travel in a straight line until it encounters a magnetic field. The problem is that I have one toolbox for the code that the magnetic sensor uses and another toolbox that makes the robot travel in a straight line. Is it possible to make use of both toolboxes at once?

The toolbox I use for the magnetic sensor I got from

https://wiki.qut.edu.au/download/attachments/172135780/EV3.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1391352088000&api=v2

And the toolbox for the movement of the robot is Mathlabs own Lego Mindstorms toolbox and the code I use is the one you get when you type edit('gostraight_closeloop.m')

When I need to use the toolbox for the magnetic sensor I need to type:

b = Brick('ioType','usb');

And when I need to use mathlabs own toolbox to move the robot I need to type:

mylego = legoev3('usb');

Is it possible that I can use both of these toolboxes at once?

Comment: Yes, for sure it is possible, actually often you use more than one tool boa at a time when you srite a MatLab code. The only thing you have to do is to make sure both the tool boxes folders are registeres in the [MatLab path](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html). The only problem you might have is if, in the two toolboxes, there is a functiion with the same name; in that case, the one in the toolbox which is registered first in the path will be executed.

Comment: Just try it. If you encounter specific problems, because you added both toolboxes to your path, ask again.

Comment: Hi! 
I managed to add the special toolbox needed for the magnetic sensor in

C:\Users\Urban\Documents\MATLAB\Add-Ons\Toolboxes\QUT EV3 MATLAB toolkit\code

Comment: And I can see all the toolboxfiles included in Matlabs own toolbox:
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b\toolbox\target\supportpackages\ev3
 C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b\toolbox\target\supportpackages\ev3\blocks
 C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b\toolbox\target\supportpackages\ev3\blocks\mex
 C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b\toolbox\target\supportpackages\ev3\registry
 C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b\toolbox\target\supportpackages\ev3\ev3demos

Comment: C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b\toolbox\target\supportpackages\ev3\ev3templates
 C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2017b\toolbox\realtime\targets\ev3io

Comment: But the problem still remains that I can't run both 
b = Brick('ioType','usb'); 
needed for the magnetic sensor and
mylego = legoev3('usb');
needed for the movement of the lego robot. Both of those are needed for setting up MATLAB and EV3 communications for each of their respective tasks, but they don't seem to be able to work together at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'can't run'? What happens when you try?

Comment: I get the following error message, when I run the mylego = legoev3('usb'); before  b = Brick('ioType','usb');
Error: File: Brick.m Line: 54 Column: 1
Illegal use of reserved keyword "classdef".
Error in twothousandeighteen (line 84)
b = Brick('ioType','usb');
I sent a email to the proffessor who made the b = Brick('ioType','usb'); and he said:

Comment: "Both these toolboxes have a constructor 
> b = Brick('ioType','usb');
> mylego = legoev3('USB’);
which creates some sort of object that other functions/methods use.  The objects are different but they will have some common properties.  One will be a handle to a communications channel.
My guess is the best thing to do is
> mylego = legoev3('USB’);
and extract the communications handle.

Comment: Modify the Brick constructor so you pass in the handle, create the object but without actually trying to open the usb device again."

So I am trying to understand what it is he mean and it isn't going so good.